# "Это неважно" или "Это не важно"

Tags: частица-не, наречия, слитно-раздельно

В Корпусе Русского языка можно найти в употреблении оба варианта (примерно одинаково популярны):

> Всё это *неважно*. Важно, что вы его любите, и он вас.
>
> Хулиганьё невероятное. ― Это *неважно*. ― Ну, тогда приезжай.

,

> ― Я перепутал, ― сказал Гена. ― Но это *не важно*… ― Да как *не важно*!
>
> Играть вы, наверно, не умеете, но это *не важно*.

Я так понимаю, что эти выражения взаимозаменяемые и автор решает сам что использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ВАЖНЫЙ - имеющий особенно большое значение, значительный, существенный. НЕВАЖНЫЙ - не имеющий большого значения, не заслушивающий особого внимания.

Смысл одинаковый, поэтому лучше пользоваться утвердительной конструкцией. Раздельно стоит писать в том случае, когда слово выделяется логически, в том числе при наличии тире, паузы в речи:

А всё остальное ― не важно. Утрясётся само собой.

Но это не важно… ― Да как не важно! ― Николай Васильевич воздел руки к небесам.

Answer (score 3):

В первом примере выбор слитно/раздельно можно подвести под схему написания отрицаний при наречиях: "слитно, если нет прямого или подразумеваемого противопоставления (утверждается о неважности чего-то)"; во втором примере - раздельно по причине наличия такого подразумеваемого противопоставления ("но" - уже индикатор его присутствия): мол, можно подумать, что "перепутывание" что-то меняет (важно для нашей затеи), но это не так  - это не важно.

Что касается "авторского" написания: это не совсем произвольный выбор; автор вполне может и сознательно придать тот или иной оттенок (здесь - слитностью и раздельностью написания). Если же авторство выйдет за пределы грамматики, с автором начнёт переговоры корректор издательства.

Comment: Отрицать важность и утверждать неважность - это одно и то же, поэтому надо объяснить, ЧТО ДАЕТ НАМ ОТРИЦАНИЕ, почему мы что-то отрицаем. Скрытое или явное противопоставление - это да. Например, кто-то утверждал, что это важно. Тогда вы говорите: нет, это не важно. Или вы говорите: это не важно, а важно вот что. Другой вариант: вы хотите логически подчеркнуть отрицание: Я думаю.. - Не вАжно, что ты думаешь.

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта подходят:

Теперь уже **не важно (неважно)**, какой она была дочерью и какие поступки совершала.

Это или отрицание признака (не важно), или утверждение противоположного признака (неважно).

Примеры:

Теперь уже **неважно**, как ее звали и чем она прославилась. [Евгения Озерова. Сказки атомного века (2002)]

И теперь уже **не важно**, обоснованным было это ощущение или нет. [Алексей Слаповский. Второе чтение (2000) // «Новый Мир», 2002]

Comment: Статистика. "Теперь уже не_важно" — частотность в Нацкорпусе 7:4 в пользу слитного написания.

Comment: А теперь посмотрите статистику "уже не важно" и "уже неважно", там практически поровну. Как Вы думаете, почему? Можно воспользоваться ответом Vera и подумать, что же дает нам отрицание.

Comment: Объясните мне, пожалуйста, зачем, с какой целью подняли вопросы трёхгодовалой давности? И заново дискуссия, а вопрос-то уже решён..

Comment: В смысле кем решен и почему уже  решен?  Авторы вопросов разные и ответы разные. О статистике не было речи, а она  показывает,  когда отрицание начинает употребляться чаще.

Comment: @М_Г А вот интересно, в диалоге надо использовать только раздельное написание, например:  -Тебе это важно? - Нет, не важно.

Comment: @Людмила Мне, например, не все ясно до сих пор.

Comment: @Sharon В диалоге явное отрицание того, что было в вопросе: -А? - Нет, не А. Мне кажется, это всегда пишется раздельно (верно для любого А, как сказали бы математики :-).

Comment: @М_Г Да, мне тоже кажется, что здесь нужно писать раздельно.

Comment: @Людмила это совершенно нормально, когда участники обращаются к старым вопросам, чтобы дать на них новые ответы, который, может быть, окажутся лучше старых. Цель сайта — создать библиотеку сведений о русском языке, а не только помочь конкретным вопрошающим.

Answer (score 1):

Слитное написание стало набирать популярность в последние лет 20-25. Проверьте в Нацкорпусе.

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:

1. Слитно или раздельно пишутся с *не* так называемые

предикативные наречия на -о (слова категории состояния)

типа *нетрудно видеть – не трудно видеть*: при утверждении они пишутся слитно, при отрицании – раздельно. Например:
а)  неважно, что он о нас думает;

Примечание 2. Различается написание с *не* безлично-предикативных слов на -о и созвучных с ними кратких прилагательных и наречий. Ср.: – Дать воды? – Не нужно. – Объяснение ненужно. Существенных изменений не заметно. – Пятно незаметно. – Подал знак незаметно.

В нашем случае, судя по примечанию, *Это неважно* *неважно* - это краткое прилагательное и, значит, пишется слитно.

Но, с другой стороны, в предложении *Неважно, что он о нас думает* Неважно - безлично-предикативное слово и вроде, согласно примечанию, должно писаться раздельно.

Я вижу, что мое мнение для вас неважно. (краткое прилагательное)
Неважно (не важно при отрицании), что я сделаю в следующий час. (неважно (не важно) = безразлично)
Отнюдь не важно, чем мы займемся в ближайший час.(безлично-предикативное слово)
Далеко не важно, кто пойдет на встречу с ним.(безлично-предикативное слово)
Вовсе не важно, как я поступлю с эти материалом.(безлично-предикативное слово)

Answer (score 0):

Хоть я и не эксперт в этом вопросе, но всё же попрошу заметить, что слово *неважно*, в отличие от его раздельного написания, имеет другой, переносный смысл - плохо, посредственно. Это значит, что читатель, ещё не до конца дочитав/поняв предложение, будет неосознанно вспоминать второе значение. Это же должно как-то повлиять на восприятие текста?