# Когда "не важно" пишется только раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Этот вопрос недавно активно обсуждался, в результате чего был сделан такой вывод.

["Это неважно" или "Это не важно"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46006/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Две формы написания (***не важно*** и ***неважно***) имеют сходную семантику, поэтому автор может выбрать любой вариант.

Согласно статистике, слитная форма встречается чаще, но в некоторых случаях на выбор написания НЕ могут повлиять какие-либо факторы. Но в любом случае  варианты могут считаться равноправными.

А теперь вопрос-загадка:

**Назовите синтаксическую конструкцию (придумайте предложение), в которой НЕ должно писаться только раздельно.**

То есть выбора нет, раздельную форму письма задает грамматика предложения.

Answer (score 1):

> Назовите синтаксическую конструкцию (придумайте предложение), в
>   которой НЕ должно писаться только раздельно.

Если ограничиться только грамматикой, можно использовать явное противопоставление, например: "Мне это не важно, а просто интересно".

Comment: Да, действительно, про противопоставление все забыли, а здесь чистая грамматика. Правда, я не эту конструкцию имела в виду.  Другой общеизвестный вариант - это усиление отрицания (нисколько не важно).

Comment: Да, точно! Я не догадался. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста.  (Правда, вежливые слова здесь запрещается говорить, но в качестве исключения иногда можно).

Answer (score 1):

*Не важно* пишется раздельно, когда *важно* употреблено в значении *горделиво*. Написать НЕ слитно в этом случае просто невозможно, ибо всегда подразумевается противопоставление или чувствуется явное отрицание.
Например: *не важно расхаживал (а ходил нормально); не важно восседал (а скромно присел)*.  Если же написать слитно, то сразу изменится смысл высказывания. Ср.: *ходил неважно (=плохо)*.

"Неважно" и "не важно" можно объяснить, определив сначала, какая это часть речи. Рассуждаю так:

Если "не важно" - категория состояния (слово ни от чего не зависит, сказуемое), то пишу раздельно. Вероятно, к раздельному написанию подталкивает ярко выраженная предикативность.

Вообще, слова категории состояния пишутся с НЕ и слитно, и раздельно (*неуютно, не стыдно*), но в данном случае нужно различать: в выражении "*мне не важно*" употребляется КС, а в выражениях "*положение неважно*" -  краткое прилагательное (**ср.**: *положение неважное*), *выглядишь неважно* - наречие. Прилагательное и наречие уже зависимы от существительного и глагола.

Если "неважно" - наречие, пишу слитно. Если есть *противопоставление* или слова *далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не* - раздельно.

Если "неважно" - краткое прилагательное, то пишу слитно: *признаюсь, ваше положение неважно* (от неважное)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но здесь нужно проводит анализ значения, а я имела в виду конструкцию, где раздельное написание задается только грамматикой, никакого анализа вообще не требуется. Кстати, это касается не только этого слова , а любых слов.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что  всегда раздельно пишется ***не важно*** в следующих вопросительных конструкциях:

**Разве не важно** понимать и прощать друг друга? **Не важно ли** воспитывать в себе сочувствие и сострадание ко всему живому?

А как считаете  вы?