# "Мне неважно" — можно ли слитно?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Точно может сказать: *мне там неинтересно.* То бишь скучно. Но можно ли сказать *мне неважно* в смысле *не имеет значения,* например так:

*Мне неважно, что он обо мне думает.*

Или только раздельно в этом случае?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46006/%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: Это не то, Серж.

Comment: Мне неважно (безразлично). Но: Ваше присутствие на мероприятии не важно, а малосущественно. Правила те же.  .

Comment: @Серж: то есть с местоимением сочетается слитное написание в данном случае, на ваш взгляд?

Comment: Да, Артем, именно так. Местоимение тут ни при чем.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwic4d_LtYiBAxWJQvEDHRNADHYQFnoECBQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Forfogrammka.ru%2F%25D0%25B1%25D0%25BB%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%2F%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D1%2582%25D0%25B5%25D1%2580%25D0%25B5%25D1%2581%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B5%2F%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B5%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B6%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE-%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B5-%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B6%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%2F&usg=AOvVaw242SEaE6-7MSHke_wbnacT&opi=89978449