# Это не важно / неважно уже

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Это не важно / неважно уже.

> Не важно / неважно, придёт ли он или нет, — всё равно ничего не произойдёт.

> Эта информация неважна / не важна.

Comment: Повтор темы  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46006/Это-неважно-или-Это-не-важно/447470#447470

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Это неважно" или "Это не важно"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46006/%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: Ищите ответ в «Поиске по сайту», не дожидаясь отклика на многословный заурядный вопрос!